# Get multiple result sets in EF without a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm in the process of refactoring a project that includes the use of EF. Right now there is an ASP.NET MVC ViewModel that has multiple lists. An example would be to query an populate all the information about a customer from a customer table, a list of all their orders, another list of returns, and maybe another list of "Wish List" items.

The way it's setup now each one of those Lists are populated from an EF call which is effectively a database call. So to populate that ViewModel it makes 4 calls to the database.

From my research, all the examples are of either joining multiple tables into one record set or the use of stored procedures to return multiple record sets.

In my scenario it's much more difficult to create an Oracle stored procedure than to just use EF to populate the Lists so I would prefer not to use stored procedures.

Are there any suggestions or examples on how I can populate multiple lists that have different queries using one EF call without a stored procedure? I'm trying to reduce the number of database calls.

Comment: How much faster do you think that making 1 call instead of 4 will be?

Comment: Why don't you join your linq-queries then?

Comment: I don't know how much faster it be going from 4 to 1 calls but I would assume it would be quicker especially if the user is on a mobile device.

Comment: As for joining the queries, if I were to go that route then what I'm imagining is a bunch of records. If there were say 1 customer record, 25 orders, 10 returns, and 100 wish list items then would that be 136 records with a potentially a bunch of fields that may or may not be populated? Then instead of just looking at the Wish List item count to determine if I display the items or not I would still have to loop through all 136 records? I'm sure that would work but sure seems like a bunch of looping through records unnecessarily.

Comment: "especially if the user is on a mobile device". Query speed has nothing to do with the client device. The query will take the same length of time regardless of what sort of device invoked it - all the server sees is a HTTP request which triggers the query. It runs completely independent the original device.

Comment: The issue of "speed" with mobile devices is generally around the size of the HTML (or JSON or XML) data returned to it (regardless how that data was created by the server) and the bandwidth and CPU power available to the device user. You've conflated the finished output itself with the means of creating it.

Comment: If you can stomach a stored procedure though, it generally will produce a performance improvement (regardless of the client device) because a) it's pre-compiled and optimised before you run it, and b) from what I know of EF it often creates horrible SQL (certainly when used with SQL Server it does, dunno if it's the same with Oracle) which isn't very efficient. It would reduce the number of calls to the DB, although not necessarily the number of actual SELECT queries executed.

Comment: It's hard to see how you could use EF to make one call to run multiple queries by any other means - the whole point of that kind of library and its structure is to allow you to write code which is equivalent to a single database query. It basic creates an abstraction layer on top of SQL, with syntax that it can translate back into SQL at runtime. So you can't do anything with it that you can't do in native SQL. And in SQL, a single SELECT can't return multiple result sets, and it can't return from multiple tables without using JOINs.

Comment: You said "From my research, all the examples are of either joining multiple tables into one record set or the use of stored procedures to return multiple record sets.". I'd say that's pretty much because those are your only two options. If you can't think of a SQL statement that would do what you want, then there won't be an EF equivalent, because of the reasons I gave above.